# Increase spacing on y axis tick labels ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels, spacing

I would like to increase the spacing of the y-axis ticks in order to make the graph (labels) more readable. How can I achieve this?

```
packages_list <- c("dplyr", "data.table", "ggplot2", "mondate", "tidyr", 
"lubridate", "stringr", "ggrepel")
lapply(packages_list, require, character.only = TRUE)

company <- paste(1:61, rep(LETTERS), sep = "")
mort_table <- rep_len(c(6065, 7680, 8590, 9500), length.out = 61)
disc_rate <-  rep_len(c(3,4), length.out = 61)

data <- data_frame(company = company, disc_rate = disc_rate, mort_table = 
mort_table)
ggplot(data, aes(x = company, y= disc_rate, label = disc_rate)) + 
  geom_point(aes(color = factor(mort_table)), size = 6, show.legend = T) + 
  geom_text(color = "white", size = 1.5) +
  geom_hline(yintercept=3.5, size=1, linetype="dotted", color="red") +
  theme(panel.grid.major.x = element_line(), legend.position = "top") + 
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Comment: the space between the ticks, depends on the ratio betwee the width of the graph and the heigth.. so you export you graphics in the format you want, using a portrait format. Also you can reduce the size of your y axis label in the theme option

Comment: @timat, if I were to export in landscape it would overlap also. Thats why I want the y-axis to stretch out

Comment: I repeat that the space between the tick is directly dependent on the "width and height" of the chart.. Even if you draw it by hand.. So you need a portrait orientation (or custom), or if you want a portrait, a very very very big screen.. (same as if you would draw it by hand). what the difference between use portrait orientation, stretch out the y-axis, or strech out the R studio windows y-axis ?

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I could come up with. This reduces the number of tick labels to 5.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(forcats)

company <- paste(1:61, rep(LETTERS), sep = "")
mort_table <- rep_len(c(6065, 7680, 8590, 9500), length.out = 61)
disc_rate <-  rep_len(c(3,4), length.out = 61)

data <- tibble(company, disc_rate, mort_table) 

axis_levels <- 
    data %>%
    mutate(company = fct_inorder(company)) %>%
    pull(company) %>%
    .[seq(1, nlevels(.), length = 5)] %>%
    as.character()

data %>%
    mutate(company = fct_inorder(company)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = company, y = disc_rate, label = disc_rate)) + 
    geom_point(aes(color = factor(mort_table)), size = 6, show.legend = TRUE) + 
    geom_text(color = "white", size = 1.5) +
    geom_hline(yintercept = 3.5, size = 1, linetype = "dotted", color = "red") +
    theme(panel.grid.major.x = element_line(), legend.position = "top") + 
    scale_x_discrete(breaks = axis_levels) +
    coord_flip()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-03-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>